# How does object initialization ambiguity get resolved?

Tags: c++, class, initialization

The class has two constructors, one that has no initialization value and does not increase
the 'val', the other takes a reference to an object, and increases 'val'.
How come, by initializing with 'A a,b = a;' a.get << b.get outputs '22' ?
I expected '12'.
Many thanks in advance.

```
class A
{
    int *val;
public:
    A() { val = new int; *val = 0;  }
    A(A &a) { val = new int; *val = a.get(); }
    int get() { return ++(*val); }
    ~A () { delete val; }
};


main:
[...]
   
    A a,b = a;
    cout << a.get() << b.get(); // 22 ????
    //cout << a.get(); // 1 if A a init, 2 if A a = a init, OK.
    //cout << a.get() << b.get(); // 33 if A a = a, A b = a init.
                                
[...]
```

Comment: It would be less confusing if you your `get()` function and copy constructor didn't modify the (source) class as most programmers expect.

Comment: There is a simple way to resolve such mysteries. Set a break point in `get()`. Then run in a debugger. Every time the debugger stops in the break point, you look into the call stack from where it does "come from".

Comment: Why do you think there is an "object initialization ambiguity"?

Answer (score 1):

Because in the `A` copy-constructor (which should really take its arguments as a reference to a `const`) you call `a.get()`. That increases `*a.val` from `0` to `1`.

Then you call `a.get()` for the output, which increases `*a.val` from `1` to `2`.

To get the expected behavior you should copy `*a.val` directly instead:

```
A(A const& a)
    : val(new int(*a.val))
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` is default-constructed, so it sets `*(a.val)` to 0.

`b` is copy-constructed from `a`,  so it first calls `a.get()`, incrementing `*(a.val)` to 1 and returning that new value, so `*(b.val)` gets set to 1, not 0.

Then you print the output of calling `a.get()` and `b.get()`, incrementing both `*(a.val)` and `*(b.val)` to 2 and returning those new values.

That is why you see `22` displayed.